# Cleaning up heatmarks

Tags: repair, cleaning

So, I accidentally left the electric stove on for... a night. Luckily, no fire, but there's a significant heatmark on the wooden cabinet next to it. I was not able to scrub it off, and it rather seems like it burned from the inside out or something because there is a nearly circular brown-ish mark visible.

Is there anything that can be done at this point?

[image: (I know my wall is a bit grimy otherwise, but it's the big spot on the left that's the concern.)]

*Reposted from Seasoned Advice*

Comment: A photo would be helpfully. Sometimes heat damages the finish and sanding and refinishing is all that is required. In other cases a new surface is needed like adding a thin sheet of brushed, stamped or polished metal (copper, aluminum and stainless) are things I have used in the past but we really need a photo.

Comment: @EdBeal Getting you a photo asap

Comment: To Ed's point, a photo would help, but I'm going on a limb here, regardless if the cabinet is veneer, laminate, or varnished, you are probably seeing a melted effect*(or cooked) and therefor probably not going to be something easily remedied

Comment: @noybman That may be exactly the case...

Comment: picture is not clear, but looking at it, I'd say just paint it?

Comment: @noybman I was trying to avoid that because I'm in a rental house. But it may just have to be the way.